# Why adding '?' type of special character in blob

Tags: javascript, csv, blob, export-to-csv, filesaver.js

In my project I want to export my data to `csv` format. It is working fine but its add a special character in first index. Why??

```js
var blob = new Blob([
    'Modified On,Created By,Name,Start Time, ...'
], {
    type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"
});
var filename = "mycsvfile.csv";
saveAs(blob, filename);
```

```html
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/1.1.20151003/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
```

When I opened in my vs-code editor It is showing a special character.
[image]

How can I solve this.

Comment: When opening with notepad, notepad++, excel and vs-code there is no special characters for me.

Comment: but I attached a screen shot of vs-code. It is showing a special character

Comment: When you open the same file in notepad or notepad++ does it look correct? as i would say this is just an environment issue, vs-code not knowing what language to read

Comment: It's probably the UTF-8 BOM (byte order mark).

Comment: When I opened this file in notepad++, gedit it looks correct.  @tyler_mitchell

Comment: can you explain @DarthJDG

Comment: Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

It's also in the Filesaver.js documentation, have a look at `disableAutoBOM`.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a BOM (Byte Order Mark)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Notepad++ (under encoding menu) has the option to save this without the BOM or search for BOM removers.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
change the type of the file

```
type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'
```

to

```
type: 'application/octet-binary'
```

Now it is working fine.